# Плиточная сетка работа со строками

Tags: jquery

Делаю плиточную сетку, не могу понять, как работать с каждой строкой. Все работает, но только для одной строки. Суть такая: есть предыдущая строка, в ней есть элементы, из этих элементов забираем высоту каждого. И есть следующая строка, в которой мы забираем из элементов offset().top. И пишем для элементов следующей строки верхний отрицательный маржин (-оффсет элементов следующей строки + высота элементов предыдущей строки). Все работает, но только для одной строки, как сделать так, чтобы скрипт работал со всеми предыдущими/следующими строками?

```js
var g = 50, off = [], h = [], total = [];
$('.row').prev().children().each(function(j){
 h[j] = $(this).height();       
});

$('.row').next().children().each(function(i){
 off[i] = $(this).offset().top;
 total[i] = -off[i]+h[i];
 $(this).css('margin-top', + total[i] + g + 'px');
});

$('h2').text('height: ' + h + ' | ' + 'offset: ' + off);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]